# Initializing members of UIViewController subclass once

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have `UIViewController` subclass. I have some members on it. I just wanted to know/confirm regarding the place to properly initialize the members. Note: I have a `storyboard` not `nib`.
Here is the interface:

```
@interface FractionCalculatorViewController : UIViewController{
  @private
    NSMutableString *outputString;
    Fraction *firstFraction;
}
```

Should I initialize output string and first fraction in `viewDidLoad`, like first checking if variable is null and then allocating and initializing it ? Or there is some proper way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to check them as null. You should allocate and initialize them in viewDidLoad method. They will be initialize when the view is loaded in the memory at once only. Below is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    outputString=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    firstFraction=[[Fraction alloc] init];

}
```

if you want to initialize variables once for the application then place the variables in AppDelegate class.

Comment: Does it means viewDidLoad will call everytime whenever viewcontroller is visible to screen or coming active from another screen or from background?

Comment: No, viewDidLoad is called once when the class is loaded in the device. If you release the object of that class and again create an object of that class and push your navigation controller to it, then again viewDidLoad of that class will be called. viewDidApear is called every time when the view of that class appear in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply initialize them in `viewDidLoad` :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    firstFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

don't forget to release them in dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {

  [outputString release];
  [firstFraction release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize them in `viewDidLoad` they gets initialized each time the controller loads its view. According to your business logic it might be incorrect, because probably you want to initialize them only once and then reuse each time for new iteration in ViewController's lifecycle. To my mind it's better to initialize such data in constructor like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *productsToBuy;

//...

@end

@implementation

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        _productsToBuy = @[@"Milk", @"Bread", @"Cheese", @"Nuts"].mutableCopy;

        //...
    }

    return self;
}

//...

@end
```